# How to input a list of quantities into one function and print the output to console

Tags: python, random

I have a list of quantities (100,500,1000].  I want to generate random numbers between 0 and 10, 100 times, 500 times, 1000 times.  I want to do this in one call and print the output to the console.

```
def random_array(n): #define function to generate the random array
    array_a = []
    for i in range(0, n, 1):
        array_a.append(randint(0, 10))
    return array_a
```

Comment: How does this code relate to what you want to do?

Comment: you can make another function that takes `[100,500,1000]` as input and loops through using  `random_array` each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
 #for choosing random number 100, 500,1000 times 
times=[100,500,1000]    # taking no of times as a list

final_array=[]

def random_array(a):  
    for i in range(a):
        rand_num=random.randint(0,10)         
        final_array.append(rand_num)
    print(final_array)            

for i in range(len(times)):     # passing each value in times as a parameter
    random_array(times[i])

# output will generate 3 arrays of 100,500,1000 times randomly generated integers
```

Comment: this will create 3 different array as per your need with specified lenght in times array.

Answer (score 0):

you could try like below by using two loop one for number of list item and another for number of random generation

```
import random
from random import randint
list1 = [100,500,1000]
list=""

times_run=0
for item in list1: 
    while times_run<=item: --loop for number of times random generation
        gen1=random.randint(0, 10)
        list=str(list)+str(gen1)+" " --for separating each generated values
        times_run+=1

print (list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you want, so if this is not what you want then you should explain a bit further.

```
ls=[100,500,1000]
ls2=[]
def random_array(ls,ls2):
    for i in ls:
        for x in range(0,i):
            ls2.append(random.randint(0,10))
random_array(ls,ls2)
print(ls2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy library for this.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(low=0,high=10, size=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `random` and `_ in for loop` as below

```
import random as random
array_a = []
n = (100,500,1000)
for k in n:
    array_a.append([random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(k)])
print(array_a)
```